# what is active solution configuration in vs 2012 configuration manager?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am using vs 2012. in the Active solution configuration dropdown list, I have 3 configurations there ("Dev", "QA", "Production").

when I run this application locally, and "QA" is selected as Active solution configuration.  I still have local connection string, not the qa one.  my understanding is it should use the QA web.config file.  am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my understanding is it should use the QA web.config file. am i wrong?

Actually you are wrong. `web.QA.config` will be used only when you publish your application but not while running it in Visual Studio where the standard `web.config` is always used.

Comment: thanks for your help.  in the Active solution configuration dropdown list,  If I select QA  as my active configuration. what does it  do?